# dynamic Objects with variables in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic

Is it possible to build dynamic objects having the property name set to the value of a variable?

for instance this seems standard...

```
dynamic elem = new Object();
elem.Name = "myName";
```

but how would this be implemented?...

```
string fn = "FirstName";
string ln = "LastName";
dynamic elem = new Object();
elem.fn = "John";
elem.ln = "Doe";
```

where as i would be able to call the properties like...

```
string fn = elem.FirstName;
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: thanks, I tried that earlier but... "Additional information: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'".  Not dealing with a dictionary here.  The dynamic Object could have many properties, not just a key and a value.

Comment: `for instance this seems standard...` No It can not work, object doesn't have a property *Name*..... Post compilable/correct code

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: There is not a mechanism in C# to macro-replace member names.  Seems like an indexer is the most appropriate solution, which means you can use a simple `Dictionary<string,object>`. If that does not meet your needs then please add to your question, but the syntax you propose is not possible in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ExpandoObject also implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, meaning you can add properties using a string key.

```
dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();

person.FirstName = "Alex";
var ln = "lastname";

(person as IDictionary<string, Object>)[ln] = "KeySmith";
```

Comment: I've noticed a -1, any feedback would be a appreciated. Of course making use of dynamic / expandobject should be carefully considered, however I believe this is answering the question at hand.